# UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION in App.g.i.cs page in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, unhandled-exception

whenever I go to one page to another page like mainpage.xaml to profile.xaml page UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION occured.its go to global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); in app.g.i.cs page.please help me how to handle this exception.Thanks in advance.

My sample code is:

```
private async void profile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile), 0);
            });

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }



        }
```

Comment: I don't know what happend.please help me.

Comment: did you try clean and rebuild?

Comment: @NishchithUchil Yes.but not working.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>
 {
       Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));                       
 });
```

Comment: thankyou for your response. I will try and tell you.

Comment: private async void profile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile), 0);
            });

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            


        }